# make user see all of my published application in google play store

Tags: android

I am these codes to redirect a app user to see all my published apps in google play. The problem is I am confused what to write in place of -publisher_name. How is that different from developer's name?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>");
        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        try {
            startActivity(goToMarket);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            startActivity(new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:<publisher_name>")));
        }
```

Comment: Publisher == Developer Account

Comment: means what i have to mention there? Still not clear. I have to write my email?

Comment: Not your e-mail, see my answer, if you want details use the links provided, and of course, try it out! You can try it out by entering another Developer Name, just to see that it works, if you dont have any Apps yet...

Answer (score 1):

It is described at the Developer Page for Android.

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningPublisher

http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#android-app

Quote:
"
From an Android app:

```
market://search?q=pub:<publisher_name>
```

Here's an example:

[http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:Google+Inc.](http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub%3aGoogle+Inc.)